# Как привести даты в ISO к одному часовому поясу?

Tags: javascript, node.js, время, datetime

```
            const dd1 = '2018-05-23T11:54:00+03:00';
                const dd2 = '2018-05-23T11:58:00+06:00';
```

Мне надо найти разницу в минутах между этими двумя датами на сервере использую 
https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/differenceInMinutes

Когда и там и там + 3 часа GMT работает все верно. Вот как мне не учитывать эти +3 часа, +6 часов и т.д.?

Comment: Пишу снова: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: и какой мтеод там использовать?  я вместо момента использую date-fns. не могу момент

Comment: я знаю про момент и так!

Comment: а в чём проблема? https://jsfiddle.net/j1y18hq5/

Comment: `(new Date(dd1) - new Date(dd2))/1000/60`

Comment: а если использовтаь вот это
https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMinutes
то он учитывает часы. и выдает мне например 176 минут

Comment: нужно именно с date-fns

Comment: Так 176 минут - это правильный ответ. Какой вам нужен результат?

Comment: так мне нужно именно 4 минуты

Comment: то есть механика такая. юзер на фронте вводит дату и время когда ему позвонить. 
на бэк уходит дата и время в формате ИСО.
далее . я на бэке проверяю разницу между текущим временем и той введенной датой им. Если время меньше текущего или между ними разница меньше 15 минут, то невалидная дата

Comment: то есть разница 15 минут как бы по локальному времени 
его времени

Comment: если вот так, то работает

 const dd1 = '2018-05-23T11:54:00+03:00';
                const dd2 = '2018-05-23T11:58:00+03:00';

Comment: если gmt совпадают

Comment: Ну, если Вам нужно игнорировать часовой пояс (что несколько странно, но хозяин - барин), то просто удалите его из всех Ваших дат.

Comment: ну а если с часовым поясом. 
то есть валидация даты должна быть в засимиости от его времени, а не от того которое на сервере

он ввел 21-50, на сервере дата для него 21-55 будет невалидна